# Telegram API BadRequest error after calling sendMediaGroup with specific videos

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telegram-api

I am trying to make telegram bot using library [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot). One of the features of my bot is to send Instagram’s stories to the user. For this feature I am using method `sendMediaGroup` with several `InputMediaVideo` or `InputMediaPhoto` in the input.

For example (Instagram link is available only for 24 hours, perhaps at the time you read this, it is no longer valid):

```py
def input_media_group_test(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.bot.sendMediaGroup(
        update.message.chat.id,
        [
            InputMediaVideo('https://scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t50.2886-16/88545009_217343653444163_3673202947982720032_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InZ0c192b2RfdXJsZ2VuLjcyMC5zdG9yeS5kZWZhdWx0In0&_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=111&_nc_ohc=2Hc1-g9OjDEAX85a-aD&vs=17858017211381000_2586017057&_nc_vs=HBkcFQAYJEdQRVdSd1ZEX2tGRHJNVUFBQ0I4YmFhZTF2a3lidXFIQUFBQRUAAsgBACgAGAAbAYgHdXNlX29pbAExFQAAJpCr%2B6S08bg%2FFQIoAkMzLBdAFAAAAAAAABgSZGFzaF9iYXNlbGluZV8xX3YxEQB16AcA&_nc_rid=ce28126395&oe=60068925&oh=46f6f85c7e36f37b578c7319a70191bc'),
            InputMediaVideo('https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4')
        ]
    )
```

The code above sends two videos (first from the Instagram) to the user. After I send a command calling this code to my bot I get following error: `telegram.error.BadRequest: Wrong file identifier/http url specified`. What am I doing wrong?

If I use the second url instead of the first one everything works fine, the problem arises only when using Instagram's urls for the videos (photos with `InputMediaPhoto` works fine).

Also I can send the Instagram video separately, just by calling `sendVideo` method with the Instagram's video link in the input, but I am trying to send a batch of videos or photos in this bot.